# Trying to get TWRP working, healthd is not present in stock ROM

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, samsung-touchwiz, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-lite

I'm a TWRP maintainer for the SM-T110 *(Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 Lite)*, and I'm trying to fix some issues I get while booting up TWRP. The device halts for a while during boot time, and then TWRP starts. [Here are the logs that are related with the issue.](https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/raw/afonohadem)

I tried getting the `healthd` binary from the stock TouchWiz firmware, but it is not present in `/sbin/healthd` where it should be. I've also done an entire `find` search, and no file named `healthd` is present. I am stuck on how to fix this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved by using SM-T210's `/sbin/healthd` file instead. The two share the same SoC and the kernels were quite similar so it worked perfectly.